# How can i add multiple parameters to an imap fetch-request?

Tags: imap

Is it possible to add multiple parameters in a fetch request?

(WORKING) Request only body with a few parameters:

```
icFetch FETCH 1 (body[header.fields (from to subject date)])\r\n
```

(NOT WORKING) Request body with a few parameters and flags:

```
icFetch FETCH 1711:* (body[header.fields (from to subject date)]) (FLAGS (\Unseen))\r\n
```

Thank you!

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep, you've got extra brackets!

You want
`icFETCH 1711:* (BODY[HEADER.FIELDS (...)] FLAGS UID INTERNALDATE)`

I don't think you can fetch just a specific flag like that though.

Comment: This was exactly what I needed. The documentation is surprisingly completely absent.